# How to install latest version of Okular on Ubuntu 14.04 (avoiding source install)?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, okular

Is there a way to install Okular in its latest version on Ubuntu 14.04? So far the default Ubuntu repository supports a really old version of Okular (offered by KDE Applications version 4.13.3), as one can confirm by running:

```
apt-cache show okular | grep Version
```

The latest version now is 1.6 (offered by KDE Applications version 18.12.2).

I know that someone can install the latest version from source code (as described in [Okular's official webpage](https://okular.kde.org/download.php)), but I want to avoid that and get an easier way to install.

I have also searched for Ubuntu 14.04 binary repositories on launchpad and I haven't found Okular in its latest version.

Am I doomed to update to a newer Ubuntu release to get the latest version of Okular, or is there a way to stack with my beloved Ubuntu 14.04 for a little longer before they get deprecated?

Answer (score 2):

The good news are that there is a way to do that and also by installing **official binaries**! That's thanks to [snap and its availability on Ubuntu 14.04](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/03/30/snaps-are-now-available-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-desktop-and-server). Snap is supported until the EOL of Ubuntu 14.04. You can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install snapd
```

But be careful, since it may install the newest linux kernel for Ubuntu 14.04 (Ver. 4.4.0 - if it isn't already installed) replacing the older one and if you are really unlucky, there might be issues for that. So take a backup before installing!

After the installation, restart your system and then execute the below commands to install Okular from the [official snap](https://snapcraft.io/okular):

```
sudo snap install core
sudo snap install okular
```

The first snap package may be installed by default, but install it just in case. It is the runtime environment of snap and it is necessary for running snap apps.

That's it! Now you have the latest version of Okular installed in your good old Ubuntu 14.04 !